# What is the meaning of ::~

Tags: c++

In the following piece of code, what is the meaning of   ::~

```
GaussianMex::~GaussianMex()
{
   int i;
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is not a single operator `::~`, but a definition of GaussianMex destructor. You define class methods by `ClassName::ClassMethod` syntax and since destructor name is `~ClassName` resulting destructor definition is `ClassName::~ClassName`.

Answer (score 7):

This is a destructor.

Consider:

```
class GaussianMex
{
public:

    // This is the CONstructor (ctor).  It is called when an instance of the class is created
    GaussianMex()
    {
    };

    // This is a Copy constructor (cctor).  It is used when copying an object.
    GaussianMex(const GaussianMex& rhs)
    {
    };


    // This is a move constructor.  It used when moving an object!
    GaussianMex(GaussianMex&& rhs)
    {
    };


    // This is the DEStructor.  It is called when an instance is destroyed.
    ~GaussianMex()
    {
    };


    // This is an assignment operator.  It is called when "this" instance is assigned
    // to another instance.
    GaussianMex& operator = (const GaussianMex& rhs)
    {
        return *this;
    };


    // This is used to swap two instances of GaussianMex with one another.
    friend void swap(GaussianMex& lhs, GaussianMex& rhs)
    {
    };
};  // eo class GuassianMex
```

The purpose of a constructor is to do any initialisation that is required (perhaps allocating memory, or other class instances).  The destructor does the opposite - it performs the clean up of any resources the class allocated during its' lifetime.

Comment: Bzzt! *tazes for saying "called on a class"*

Comment: @Kos, fair play :)  *is tasered*

Comment: You forgot the copy and move constructors, and assignment operator! *slap*

Comment: What about overriding `delete`? That's the bestest place for cleanup code!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, bah - edited :)

Comment: Haha you _actually_ did it. Nice.

Comment: +1 for effort despite the typos in all the names except for the classname

Comment: Now now, where's your global overload of `swap`? :)

Comment: @Kos, ask and ye shall receive :P

Comment: Great! We are now able to implement both the assignment ops using CAS as described in [one of the the best C++ answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) :-)

Answer (score 3):

It indicates that the method is a destructor.

Your class can have at most one destructor, and it is always the name of the class prefixed with the `~` symbol.

The destructor is called whenever an instance of your object is destroyed. This happens whenever an instance goes out of scope, or when you call `delete` on a pointer to an instance the the class.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining the destructor of the class `GaussianMex`.